# php package installation with yum

Tags: php, centos7, php-7.2

I am really sorry if I am asking something that's been already asked, but I couldn't find anything relevant after spending a good amount of time.

I've done:

```
yum install -y php72-php-pecl-xdebug
```

(This is from remi repo)

Now if the plugin is not really activated, if I look at where the package was really installed is:

```
# locate php | grep xdebug
/etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/15-xdebug.ini
/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
... more files listed
```

Why do I get all this files inside /opt/remi/etcetc? Coudln't all these file be copied to where php is really looking for? which would be exactly the same just stripping "opt/remi/php72/root/" ? even the .ini file why does it go inside an /opt directory inside /etc? Is it because I have several versions of php installed?

It all smells to me that I am not doing what I am expected to do, right? Should I make a symbolic link for the .ini file and the .so file to get the module working? That also looks wrong... Can you kind of explain to me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explain in the [repository FAQ](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl)

**php72-*** packages are software collections, designed for parallel installation (allow multiple versions installation simultenaously).

If you need a single version, in standard directory, use the **php-*** packages (from remi-php72 repository).

As explained by the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).